# Сломалась ссылка на утверждённую правку

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, ссылки, утверждённые-правки, история-правок

К примеру, https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/8547/revisions

Ссылка просто плейн текстом выводится:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уже нормально отображается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Об ошибке и ее устранении сообщено на MSE:

["Edit Approved" links are showing as plain text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323136/339911)

Разработчик перестарался :)

Comment: Я тоже сообщил в тоже время (: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323138/260198

Comment: @Suvitruf на пару минут позже :)

Comment: Я долго думаю, прежде, чем пост написать :D

Comment: @Suvitruf потому и дубликат. Надо сначала постить, а потом в 5 минут быстро делать неревизируемые правки. Правда кто-то может своим комментом эту цепочку сломать.